# Update column data for 200k records with subset of existing column data

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

We have existing table in Oracle 10g database where column data is like

1-13,1-35,1-45,1-57,1-59,1-F,2-1,2-10,2-11,2-13,2-14,2-16,2-17,2-20,2-215,2-216,2-24,2-25,2-27,2-28,2-29,2-30,2-31,2-34,2-35,2-36,2-38,2-39,2-40,2-41,2-44,2-45,2-46,2-48,2-49,2-5,2-50,2-9,3-N,4-1,4-10,4-11,4-12,4-13,4-14,4-15,4-16,4-17,4-18,4-19,4-2,4-20,4-25,4-26,4-7,4-9

and requirement is to remove all '1-x' values and update the value.

There are 200,000+ records present in the table.

What would be best possible fastest solution (db query / procedure) for this?

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  What does the *table* look like?  What are the *columns*?

Comment: Table name is 'USERS' where we have all users details for an application.  User ID, FirstName, LastName etc.. and one column called 'APP_FEATURES' and it has such type of values.

Comment: I strongly suggest you normalize the database model at least to 3NF. At the moment is does not even reach 1NF.

Comment: "There are 2 lacs plus records present in the table." - What is the meaning of this sentence? Also please show your current attempt. Replacement of some value in the column is a common task at was asked here thousands of times

Comment: @astentx A lakh (or lac) is 100,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> requirement is to remove all '1-x' values and update the value.

You can use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET appl_feature_access_cds
      = LTRIM(
          REGEXP_REPLACE(
            ',' || appl_feature_access_cds,
            ',1-[^,]+'
          ),
          ','
        );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f522d8693bea6e907bc722ba2a165f3)*